# disable new Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I want to disable the new Microsoft Edge running on an HP laptop equipped with Windows 10.  Various instructions say select the Microsoft Edge folder, right click the mouse, and then rename the folder.  However, the "rename" option does not appear after right-clicking.

Comment: What is the full path to the folder you are attempting to rename?  What is the contents of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\83.0.478.58\Installer`?  Are you attempting to restore Legacy Edge?  It's not necessary to remove Microsoft Edge in order to use Legacy Edge.  Please edit your question, do not submit a comment, and provide this necessary vital information required to answer your question[.](https://betanews.com/2020/07/07/uninstall-microsoft-edge/)

Comment: I am in agreement with the above post, but as an alternative thought, the new Edge is really quite good and is the direction going forward. Legacy Edge will not last forever. I have two production machines with new Edge and one Insider Machine with both new and legacy. I do not use legacy Edge any more.  Just a different point of view for you to consider.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the folder and pressing F2?

Answer (score 1):

Taking ownership of Windows sensitive folders is a bad idea that can backfire
in the future. Instead, try the following.

**To disable Microsoft Edge from running at the background:**

1. Open the Settings app
2. Select *Privacy*, then *Background apps*
3. On the "Background apps" page find "Microsoft Edge" and click it to Off.

**To totally remove Microsoft Edge**

This method has unknown side-effects on Windows and it is unknown for how long
it will be effective.

The tool to use is Technet's PowerShel script
[Windows 10 Store Apps Uninstaller](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Windows-10-Store-Apps-5f60b9e3).

This script lets remove some of the built-in apps that Windows otherwise
won’t let you remove.
It will only remove the Windows app for the user account currently logged on.

Comment: Does this answer apply to Microsoft Edge or Legacy Edge.  It’s not necessary to use third-party software to remove Microsoft Edge.